# How can I know whether RabbitMQ application has started

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, erlang, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a c# code that installs rabbitmq 3.7.4, erlang 20.2 on windows server 2012 R2 and I need to know when the application (not the service) has started. After running `rabbitmq-service install` and `rabbitmq-service start` I'm looking for a command line that will indicate that the application is running. I'm aware of the `wait pid_file, wait --pid pid` command but can't locate the pid file on my machine. The documantaion says:

> This command will wait for the RabbitMQ application to start at the node. It will wait for the pid file to be created if pidfile is specified

specified where?

rabbitmq-echopid.bat returns:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, RabbitMQ does not create a PID file by default, so you have to discover the PID and then pass it as an argument: `rabbitmqctl.bat wait -P PID`

To discover the PID, you can run the following using the name of your RabbitMQ node:

```
.\rabbitmq-echopid.bat rabbit@my-hostname
```

At this time, there is a bug where `The system cannot find...` will be echoed before the PID is echoed. I filed [this bug](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1642) and will have a fix in soon, but in the meantime you can edit the `rabbitmq-echopid.bat` script to change `!TDP0!` to `%TDP0%`.

You can also use any other Windows tool to find the PID of the `erl.exe` process running RabbitMQ - see the script for an example of `wmic.exe`, or you could use `tasklist`, or Powershell, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can run the following batch script:

```
START /B rabbitmq-server

START /wait cmd /c "rabbitmq-echopid.bat -n rabbit@`hostname` > rabbitmq_pid.txt"
set /p PID=<rabbitmq_pid.txt
echo %PID%
del rabbitmq_pid.txt

cmd /c "rabbitmqctl wait -P %PID%"
```

Note that for the `rabbitmq-echopid` command to work, you have to add an `-n` before the nodename.

Moreover, in the above batch script, the nodename is dynamically generated by combining "rabbit@" withe the `hostname` windows command (inside backticks).