# How to identify the rabbitmq process in task manager?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have rabbitmq installed on my laptop. Is there a way to check if rabbitmq is running as background process by checking process in  windows task manager? I don't see anything with name rabbit mq on windows task manager. Also please share commands to check status of rabbitmq process.

Comment: You can perhaps check this thread. Seems like it covers yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349014/how-can-i-know-whether-rabbitmq-application-has-started

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can look for it in the "Services" menu:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9apHB.png

The task manager's "Services" tab might show it as well, if you need the pid:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/darnc.png

Comment: Thanks Eddie, I am able to see it under services of task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Under Details in Task Manager, mine is running as erlserv.exe. FYI - may not show as rabbit or rabbitmq.